# Eclipse. How to see source of standard functions in debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Let's say I have the following code:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push(1);
stack.pop();
```

Can I see the source of push() or pop() functions or the Stack's constructor while debugging in Eclipse? Pressing F5 is not going inside of it - just steps over. Is there some configuration needed?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you linked the JDK source code? www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-attach-jdk-source-code/

Comment: I did it and also I can see the sources by pressing F3 on functions, but debugging just steps over them :(

Comment: Did you change anything about your hotkeys? Does it work with the "Step into"-button in the debug view?

Comment: No it doesn't - I'm pressing exactly Step Into button. Also the weird thing is that it finds the Throwable.class when I'm trying to pop an item from empty stack - it goes inside throwable and do everything, but not inside the pop function

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard functions, but rather a JDK library of classes.
usually, these classes can have source attached throught the "Installed JDKs" panel of your Eclipse. Look for example [mkyong article on that subject](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-attach-jdk-source-code/)

Comment: Thank you, did it - http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140910-kr2w-63kb
But problem still exists - debugging steps over push or pop functions :( Maybe I need something more?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, select **Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs** ,
expand rt.jar, select “Source attachment” and find the src.zip from your disk drive.

src.zip is found in jdk folder

Comment: Thank you, did it - attached src.zip - still the same - not going inside of push or pop - just steps over :(

Comment: Are you debugging the java SE Stack class? If you are debugging an android project you will have to attach the source of android.jar not rt.jar.

Comment: I suggest you ctrl+click on the Stack class in your code and see where it links to. If it does not link to any source code, then it would give you an error message telling source of which jar file is missing. Now you can fix it by attaching the source.

Comment: That's the weird thing - ctrl+click is opening a source of Stack and also pressing F3 on a pop() functions opens it's declaration in Stack.class, but pressing Step Into in Eclipse just steps over it